# Graph radius in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111397/graph-radius-in-java-follow-up).)

The following snippet is a brute-force algorithm for computing a graph radius in time \$\Theta(V^2 + VE)\$ and space \$\Theta(V)\$ simply by doing \$|V|\$ breadth-first searches over each node in the graph. The graph radius is a minimum graph eccentricity of any node of the graph, where eccentricity of a node \$u\$ is the maximum distance from \$u\$ to any other graph node.

**Explanation of the graph radius concept**

What happens here is that you iterate over all nodes in the graph, and for each iterated node \$u\$, you run breadth-first search starting from \$u\$; your aim here is to find the largest distance from \$u\$ to any other node in the graph. Record all those distances associated with every iterated node, and finally return the minimum of them.

**GraphRadiusFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.radius;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import net.coderodde.graph.UnweightedGraphNode;

/**
 * This class implements a brute-force algorithm for computing the radius of 
 * an unweighted graph. The graph radius in question is defined as follows:
 * for each graph node, run breadth-first search and return the maximum length
 * from the source node to any other node. Gather the same number over all of 
 * the nodes and then pick the smallest of them.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Nov 20, 2015)
 */
public class GraphRadiusFinder {

    private Deque<UnweightedGraphNode> queue;
    private Map<UnweightedGraphNode, Integer> distanceMap;

    public GraphRadiusFinder() {}

    private GraphRadiusFinder(boolean dummy) {
        this.queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.distanceMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public int compute(UnweightedGraphNode connectedComponentRepresentative) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(connectedComponentRepresentative,
                               "The graph component representative is null.");
        GraphRadiusFinder finderState = new GraphRadiusFinder(false);
        List<UnweightedGraphNode> connectedComponent = 
                finderState.expand(connectedComponentRepresentative);

        int radius = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (UnweightedGraphNode node : connectedComponent) {
            int tentativeRadius = finderState.getMaximumDistanceFrom(node);

            if (radius > tentativeRadius) {
                radius = tentativeRadius;
            }
        }

        return radius;
    }

    private int getMaximumDistanceFrom(UnweightedGraphNode node) {
        queue.clear();
        distanceMap.clear();

        queue.addLast(node);
        distanceMap.put(node, 0);

        int maximumDistance = 0;

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            UnweightedGraphNode current = queue.removeFirst();

            for (UnweightedGraphNode child : current.children()) {
                if (!distanceMap.containsKey(child)) {
                    int distance = distanceMap.get(current) + 1;
                    distanceMap.put(child, distance);
                    queue.addLast(child);

                    if (maximumDistance < distance) {
                        maximumDistance = distance;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return maximumDistance;
    }

    private List<UnweightedGraphNode> expand(UnweightedGraphNode node) {
        queue.add(node);
        distanceMap.put(node, 0);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            UnweightedGraphNode current = queue.removeFirst();

            for (UnweightedGraphNode child : current.children()) {
                if (!distanceMap.containsKey(child)) {
                    distanceMap.put(child, 0);
                    queue.addLast(child);
                }
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(distanceMap.keySet());
    }
}
```

**UndirectedGraphNode.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements an unweighted graph node.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Nov 20, 2015)
 */
public class UnweightedGraphNode {

    private final String name;
    private final Set<UnweightedGraphNode> neighbors = new HashSet<>();

    public UnweightedGraphNode(String name) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name, "The node name is null.");
    }

    public void addNeighbor(UnweightedGraphNode neighbor) {
        this.neighbors.add(neighbor);
        neighbor.neighbors.add(this);
    }

    public Set<UnweightedGraphNode> children() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(neighbors);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (o.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        return name.equals(((UnweightedGraphNode) o).name);
    }
}
```

**PerformanceDemo.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.graph.UnweightedGraphNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.radius.GraphRadiusFinder;

public class PerformanceDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int NODES = 2000;
        int EDGES = 6000;
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        List<UnweightedGraphNode> graph = buildRandomGraph(NODES,
                                                           EDGES, 
                                                           random);
        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int radius = new GraphRadiusFinder().compute(graph.get(0));
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("Time elapsed: %.2f milliseconds, radius: %d.\n", 
                          1.0 * (endTime - startTime) / 1e6,
                          radius);
    }

    private static List<UnweightedGraphNode> buildRandomGraph(int nodes,
                                                              int edges,
                                                              Random random) {
        List<UnweightedGraphNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<>(nodes);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; ++i) {
            nodeList.add(new UnweightedGraphNode("" + i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
            choose(nodeList, random).addNeighbor(choose(nodeList, random));
        }

        return nodeList;
    }

    private static <T> T choose(List<T> list, Random random) {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

**GraphRadiusFinderTest.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.radius;

import net.coderodde.graph.UnweightedGraphNode;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class GraphRadiusFinderTest {

    private final GraphRadiusFinder finder = new GraphRadiusFinder();

    @Test
    public void testCompute() {
        UnweightedGraphNode a = new UnweightedGraphNode("A");
        UnweightedGraphNode b = new UnweightedGraphNode("B");
        UnweightedGraphNode c = new UnweightedGraphNode("C");
        UnweightedGraphNode d = new UnweightedGraphNode("D");
        UnweightedGraphNode e = new UnweightedGraphNode("E");
        UnweightedGraphNode f = new UnweightedGraphNode("F");
        UnweightedGraphNode g = new UnweightedGraphNode("G");

        a.addNeighbor(b);
        a.addNeighbor(c);
        a.addNeighbor(d);

        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(a));
        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(b));
        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(c));
        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(d));

        c.addNeighbor(d);

        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(a));
        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(b));
        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(c));
        assertEquals(1, finder.compute(d));

        c.addNeighbor(e);

        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(a));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(b));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(c));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(d));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(e));

        e.addNeighbor(f);

        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(a));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(b));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(c));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(d));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(e));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(f));

        f.addNeighbor(g);

        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(a));
        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(b));
        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(c));
        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(d));
        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(e));
        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(f));
        assertEquals(3, finder.compute(g));

        g.addNeighbor(d);

        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(a));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(b));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(c));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(d));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(e));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(f));
        assertEquals(2, finder.compute(g));
    }
}
```

So, how can I improve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>- One obvious improvement is not to use brute force. A standard approach is to pick a random vertex \$v\$, BFS find the farthest vertex \$u\$, and BFS find the vertex \$w\$ farthest from \$u\$. Notice that \$u\$ and \$w\$ form the diameter.</s>

- `compute` is not a very descriptive name. `findRadius` perhaps?
- I am not sure I understand the necessity of dummy public constructor. The

  ```
  public GraphRadiusFinder(UnweightedGraphNode connectedComponentRepresentative) {
      this.queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
      this.distanceMap = new HashMap<>();
      this.connectedComponent = expand(connectedComponentRepresentative);
  }
  ```

  looks more direct.